# My viewModel is updating the wrong variables when trying to draw a polygon

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am writing a City Map Generator app for D&D/ttrpg
Users click to create sections of a city
I am working on the City wall. Users click to mark corners of the Wall, which is then generated.

I am using a Canvas in kotlin/Jetpack Compose and a ViewModel
Firstly the User clicks the Corners, and these points are passed to ViewModel and stored in a List. This list is drawn on the canvas.
When the User clicks the 1st point again, the List is passed to a new Object (CityWall) and the list cleared.
The City Wall is then drawn.

My problem is that the in-progress List is not being drawn, until after the CityWall is created.
Then if a new Wall is created, it is drawing the final Wall, but point-by-point, as User clicks.

I have included Logs in my code, and cannot see why the City Wall is being updated onClick, as it is the inProgress wall List that should be passed the Clicks

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WallTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    val wallViewModel:WallViewModel = viewModel()
                    val wallUIState by wallViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
                    MainScreen(
                        wallViewModel = wallViewModel,
                        inProgressWall = wallUIState.inProgressWall,
                        cityWall = wallUIState.cityWall
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}//end Main Activity

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    wallViewModel: WallViewModel,
    inProgressWall: MutableList<Offset>,
    cityWall: CityWall
){

    var clickMode: ClickMode by remember { mutableStateOf(ClickMode.AWAITINGFIRSTWALLCLICK) }

    fun doClick(clickedPoint: Offset) {
        Log.d("CLICK", "at $clickedPoint")
        when (clickMode){
            ClickMode.AWAITINGFIRSTWALLCLICK -> {
                Log.d("FIRST WALL", "in progress ${inProgressWall.toString()}")
                wallViewModel.startWall(clickedPoint)
                clickMode = ClickMode.AWAITINGWALLCLICK
            }
            ClickMode.AWAITINGWALLCLICK -> {
                if ((clickedPoint - inProgressWall[0]).magnitude() < 50) {
                    Log.d("CLICK CLOSE", "$clickedPoint ${inProgressWall[0]}")
                    wallViewModel.finaliseWall()

                    clickMode = ClickMode.AWAITINGFIRSTWALLCLICK
                } else {
                    Log.d("WALL CLICK", "in progress ${inProgressWall.toString()}")
                    wallViewModel.continueWall(clickedPoint)
                    clickMode = ClickMode.AWAITINGWALLCLICK
                }
            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
    }

    Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(10.dp)
        .background(color = Color.LightGray)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onTap = { doClick(it) }
            )
        }
){

        fun drawInProgressWall(wall: MutableList<Offset>) {
            for (towerIndex in wall.indices){
                drawCircle(color = Color.Red, radius = 30f, center = wall[towerIndex])
                drawLine(
                    Color.Cyan,
                    start = wall[towerIndex],
                    end = wall[(towerIndex + 1) % wall.size],
                    strokeWidth = 5f
                )
            }
        }

        fun drawWall(wall: CityWall) {
            //todo DRAW WALL
            Log.d("DRAW WALL", wall.vertexes.toString())
            for (towerIndex in wall.vertexes.indices){
                drawCircle(color = Color.Black, radius = 30f, center = wall.vertexes[towerIndex])
                drawLine(
                    Color.Black,
                    start = wall.vertexes[towerIndex],
                    end = wall.vertexes[(towerIndex + 1) % wall.vertexes.size],
                    strokeWidth = 20f
                )
            }
        }

        drawWall(cityWall)
        drawInProgressWall(inProgressWall)

}//end canvas

    //controls
    Box(
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()

    ){
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly

        ){
Text(text = clickMode.toString())
        }
    }

}//end Main Screen
fun Offset.magnitude(): Float {
    return sqrt((this.x * this.x) + (this.y * this.y))
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class WallViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var inProgressWall: MutableList<Offset> = mutableListOf()
    var cityWall = CityWall(vertexes = mutableListOf())

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(
        WallUiState(
            inProgressWall = inProgressWall,
            cityWall = cityWall

        )
    )
    val uiState: StateFlow<WallUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun updateState() {
        Log.d("UPDATE", "InProgress is $inProgressWall")
        Log.d("UPDATE", "wall is ${cityWall.vertexes}")
        _uiState.update { it ->
            it.copy(
                inProgressWall = inProgressWall,
                cityWall = cityWall
            )
        }
    }

    fun startWall(clicked: Offset) {
        Log.d("START WALL", "at $clicked")
        inProgressWall.clear()
        inProgressWall.add(clicked)
        updateState()
    }//end Start Wall

    fun continueWall(clicked: Offset) {
        Log.d("CONTINUE WALL", "at $clicked")
        inProgressWall.add(clicked)
        updateState()
    }

    fun finaliseWall() {
        Log.d("FINISH WALL", "END")
        cityWall.vertexes = inProgressWall
        Log.d("NEW WALL BEFORE CLEAR", cityWall.vertexes.toString())
          inProgressWall.clear()
        Log.d("NEW WALL", cityWall.vertexes.toString())
        updateState()
        return
    }

}//end view model

data class WallUiState(
    val inProgressWall: MutableList<Offset>,
    val cityWall: CityWall
) {

}
```

Comment: Can you try for starters moving `doClick` out of the Composable function, that looks quite strange to me

Comment: I can try - it does mean passing it the parameters, and then I can't alter them - I need to tell it to swap mode

Comment: Your `clickMode` to me looks like a [backwards write](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#avoid-backwards), like you are writing to it inside a when statement, so having a function like that inside a composable kind of allows you to stomp all over the variable when you shouldn't be

Comment: Ah yes. ok, I see that I am doing that. How to fix, though? I need to change mode, depending on what mode I was in when clicked

Comment: I guess it is UI state, so the clickMode variable could be scrapped and moved into `wallUIState`, just so long as you don't write to it after you've read it

Comment: ok , that's something to try. thanks